# Not able to get posts from 'tryghost' with Axios error

Tags: next.js, ghost-blog

I am using Next.js and Ghost API to build a headless blog.

Following the tutorial on Youtube, I was able to follow step by step, but I am stuck at receiving the data from the 'tryghost'.

With the Ghost api_url, api_key, and api_version, I should be able to get the posts, but I am getting error with below.

AxiosError: There is no suitable adapter to dispatch the request since :

- adapter xhr is not supported by the environment
- adapter http is not available in the build
  at Object.getAdapter (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@tryghost/content-api/es/content-api.js:2027:19)
  at Axios.dispatchRequest (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@tryghost/content-api/es/content-api.js:2065:30)
  at Axios.request (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@tryghost/content-api/es/content-api.js:2363:39)
  at Axios. [as get] (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@tryghost/content-api/es/content-api.js:2388:21)
  at Function.wrap [as get] (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@tryghost/content-api/es/content-api.js:7:19)
  at defaultMakeRequest (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@tryghost/content-api/es/content-api.js:2770:27)
  at makeApiRequest (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@tryghost/content-api/es/content-api.js:2915:16)
  at Object.browse (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@tryghost/content-api/es/content-api.js:2868:20)
  at getPosts (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/ghost/post.js:13:28)
  at Home (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/page.jsx:11:78)
  at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
  at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
  code: 'ERR_NOT_SUPPORT'
  }
  { posts: undefined }

I tried to install axios dependency, but not working

Answer (score 0):

Try calling this Content API in useEffect, worked for me.

In component ->

```
useEffect(() => {
    getPosts().then((data) => {
        if (data) {
            setPosts(data);
        }
    })
}, []);
```

Common Ghost CMS apis ->

```
export async function getPosts() {
return await api.posts
    .browse({
        limit: "all",
        include: ["tags"]
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

}